# Find the components of a vector in the standard basis given a vector in the general basis

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations, change-of-basis

The vector $\vec{v}_B$ has the following components in the general basis $B$.

$\vec{v}=\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\end{bmatrix}_{B}$

$B=\left\langle \begin{bmatrix}1\\-1\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}2\\4\end{bmatrix}\right\rangle$

Find the components of the vector $\vec{v}_\cal{E}$ in the standard basis $\cal{E}$.

$\vec{v}=\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\end{bmatrix}_{{\cal E}}$

${\cal E}=\left\langle \begin{bmatrix}1\\0\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\end{bmatrix}\right\rangle$

I honestly have no idea. All help is appreciated.

Comment: Please do not delete a question after receiving an answer.  This is disrespectful to the person who took the time to answer your question, and to the community at large.

Answer (score 0):

$$\vec v=\begin{bmatrix}\color{blue}1\\\color{blue}0\end{bmatrix}_\mathcal{B}=\color{blue}1 \begin{bmatrix}1\\-1\end{bmatrix}_\mathcal{E}+\;\color{blue}0 \begin{bmatrix}2\\4\end{bmatrix}_\mathcal{E} = \begin{bmatrix}1\\-1\end{bmatrix}_\mathcal{E}$$